# Entity Framework and TFS - Code check-in after deleting entities from edmx and adding back again

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, tfs, asp.net-mvc-5

I had to change the datatype of a column in my database, after changing it I have deleted 2 tables in my edmx and saved it, then added back those 2 tables again using update model from database option and saved it.

I have then right clicked on `model.tt` and `model.context.tt` files and selected `run custom tool`, the application built successfully after these steps.

Now I want to checkin this code, when i clicked checkin in the changes window it shows that the `Employee.cs` and `Department.cs` files as deleted with horizontal line on those files, below it shows detected 2 adds and it shows `Employee.cs` and `Department.cs` files and when I selected promote it it is giving the below error.

```
 /xyx/test/myapplication/myapplication.datamodel/UserRegistration/Employee.cs already has pending changes.
```

The same error is shown for both the `Employee.cs` and `Department.cs` files.

Any help on how to proceed from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

- Treat the delete and the add/edit as individual check-ins. Delete the tables, regenerate the models, check-in the delete. Then re-add the tables, regenerate the models, check in the new files.
- Treat the regeneration as a single action. Use the undo-pending changes to get rid of the pending delete. Regenerate the models. Check in the changed files.